# Simulate FB iOS integrated dialog and pre-fill the initial text

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, ios7, fbdialogs

When using `iOS` integrated dialog box to post to `FB`, there is `API` to set the initial text that the user can alter afterwards.
But I am unable to see such an ability in `FB` native dialog boxes (not by using `FBDialogs` nor using `FBWebDialogs`).

Is there a way to pre-fill the text using `FB` dialogs?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's against policy to pre-fill the message. You shouldn't even pre-fill for the iOS integrated dialogs.

Comment: I mean pre-fill and give user the ability to edit it. Is it against policy either?

Comment: From section IV.2 of Platform Policies (https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) "You must not pre-fill any of the fields associated with the following products, unless the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow: Stream stories (user_message parameter for Facebook.streamPublish and FB.Connect.streamPublish, and message parameter for stream.publish), Photos (caption), Videos (description), Notes (title and content), Links (comment), and Jabber/XMPP."